# image height reduce/increase automatically

Tags: macros, mdframed

I have the below `boxed` environment. The image should place in the `marginpar` width. When my `environment` is going long the `image` should automatically increase upto my enviroment, when is going to low it will reduce automatically. Finally, the image height should start in `\begin{keyidea}....` and end with `\end{keyidea}`. How to achieve this. My MWE is :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphics}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,usetwoside=false]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{keyideascolor}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.1}
%%%%\includegraphics{keyiidea} keyicon marginpar image
\makeatletter
\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=keyideascolor,
          hidealllines=true,
          leftmargin=0pt,
          rightmargin=0pt,
          innerleftmargin=7pt,
          innerrightmargin=7pt,
          innertopmargin=1.75ex,
          innerbottommargin=1.25ex,
          skipabove=0pt,
          skipbelow=0pt,
          nobreak=false,
          splittopskip=2ex,
          splitbottomskip=2ex,
          roundcorner=0pt
          ]{@keyidea}

\newenvironment{keyidea}{%
  \addvspace{1.75ex}\vspace{\parskip}%
  \goodbreak
  \@keyidea
}{%
  \end@keyidea
  \null\goodbreak
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title here}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A Level Head}
\begin{keyidea}%1
\lipsum[2-3]
\includegraphics{keyiidea.pdf}
\end{keyidea}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{keyidea}%2
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{keyidea}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your box is breakable across pages and how do you expect to break a single image in the margin? Difficult!

Comment: @Harish: my box will not breakable and it'll show only one page (full/middle/partial any sizes)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not breakable and uses `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{keyideascolor}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.1}
\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{keyidea}[1][]{
  enhanced jigsaw,
  left=7pt,right=7pt,top=1.75ex,bottom=1.25ex,
  boxrule=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  before=\par\noindent\vspace{2em},
  after=\par\noindent\vspace{2em},
  colback= keyideascolor ,
  overlay={
     \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
       (d) at (frame.north east)
       {\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,height=\tcb@height]{example-image-a}};
    },
  #1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{keyidea}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{keyidea}
\begin{keyidea}
\lipsum[4]
\end{keyidea}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use different images,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{keyideascolor}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.1}
\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{keyidea}[2][]{
  enhanced jigsaw,
  left=7pt,right=7pt,top=1.75ex,bottom=1.25ex,
  boxrule=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  before=\par\noindent\vspace{2em},
  after=\par\noindent\vspace{2em},
  colback= keyideascolor ,
  overlay={
     \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
       (d) at (frame.north east)
       {\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth,height=\tcb@height]{#2}};
    },
  #1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{keyidea}{logo}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{keyidea}
\begin{keyidea}{example-image-a}
\lipsum[4]
\end{keyidea}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit after comment:

May be this is what is needed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,inner=2.8in,outer=1in,]{geometry}
%% marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm, because you want picture on the inner side and margin notes are usually on the outer side. Also you need more space on inner sides.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{keyideascolor}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.1}
\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{keyidea}[1][]{
  enhanced jigsaw,
  left=7pt,right=7pt,top=1.75ex,bottom=1.25ex,
  boxrule=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  before=\par\noindent\vspace{2em},
  after=\par\noindent\vspace{2em},
  colback= keyideascolor ,
  overlay={
     \checkoddpage
     \ifoddpage
     \begin{scope}
     \clip ([xshift=-0.2in]frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=-1.8in]frame.north west);
     \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor = north east] (a)
       at ([xshift=-0.1in]frame.north west)
       {\includegraphics[height=\tcb@height]{example-image-a}};
     \node[anchor=north east,text width=1.7in] at (a.north east) {This is image on odd page};
     \end{scope}
     \else
     \begin{scope}
     \clip ([xshift=0.2in]frame.south east) rectangle ([xshift=1.8in]frame.north east);
     \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor = north west](b)
       at ([xshift=0.1in]frame.north east)
       {\includegraphics[height=\tcb@height]{example-image-a}};
     \node[anchor=north west,text width=1.7in] at (b.north west) {This is image on even page};
     \end{scope}
     \fi
    },
  #1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\null
\newpage
\clearpage
\begin{keyidea}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{keyidea}
\begin{keyidea}
\lipsum[4]
\end{keyidea}
\clearpage
\begin{keyidea}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{keyidea}
\begin{keyidea}
\lipsum[4]
\end{keyidea}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have need to reduce the images `from top` (based on the text) and `not shrink`.

Comment: Fixed width and height is 67pt and 312pt. When text is small the picture should reduce from top of the figure height (like 1pt) to actucual text width. Text maximum height is 200pt.

Comment: How to set if `oddpage` marginpar will print `leftside` and if `evenpage` marginpar will print in `rightside`?

Comment: @Balaji That means you want the picture to be on inner side. Am I right?

Comment: Yes Harish. Exactly i would like the picture in innerside.

Comment: Like `(example-image-a)` and i found one problem now. `marginpar` is not reduce from top of the image. I would like image should start to reduce from `leftside` and `top of the height` to actual text height.